# Confused on linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm a bit confused. I got this type of matrix when I was a question regarding eigen values and eigen vectors. This is a $Ax = 0$ matrix btw.

The answer is, $x_1 = 0, x_2 = s, x_3 = 0$. I'm confused because using this logic why is $x_1 = 0$ ? ? When I first did it I got $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating $Ax=0$ you have the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=0\\
x_3=0\\
0=0
\end{cases}
$$

so the solution is a vector that has $x_1=x_3=0$ and the other component ($x_2$) can be any value.

Comment: Oh so if no value is given we have to assume its any value? Thx

Comment: Yes, $0=0$ is an identity. You can verify by direct substitution that $(0,x_2,0)$ verify the equation $\forall x_2$.